# python datastructure to find windows spanning a given time point

Tags: python, optimization, indexing, data-structures

I'm trying to optimize a piece of code of mine but I don't know which would be the best datastructure or if there even is something that does what I want.

I have a list of entities with a defined start and stop timepoint (both floats).
I'm trying to build an index which lets me lookup which windows (start and stop) span a given timepoint.
Currently I'm simply iterating the dict and check for each entity if `start < t < stop`.

Here's a small example:

```
entities = {
    'a': (0, 32.31),
    'b': (2, 22.00312),
    'c': (10, 34.1),
    'd': (22, 40.2)
}
```

Expected output would be something like this:

```
t = 12
index = build_index(entities)
candidates = find_candidates(t, index)
print(candidates)
['a', 'b', 'c']

t = 33
index = build_index(entities)
candidates = find_candidates(t, index)
print(candidates)
['c', 'd']
```

The list of entities can grow up to a couple of hundred-thousands.
What would be a good data structure/programming approach to find these windows as fast as possible on a standard laptop (lets say 8 GB of RAM)

I'm happy to any ideas for a solution, I'm not necessarily looking for a full working code which does what I want!

Comment: also, you might wanna have a look at [Segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Comment: I edited my post, thanks for pointing this out @Adam.Er8!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Adam.Er8, I was able to find a solution.

the problem is easily solved using the intervaltree module.

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree

 entities = {
    'a': (0, 32.31),
    'b': (2, 22.00312),
    'c': (10, 34.1),
    'd': (22, 40.2)
}
for key, r in entities.items():
    t[r[0]:r[1]] = key

results = t.at(12)
print([x.data for x in results])
['a', 'b', 'c']
```